# Null pointer exception when entering activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a null pointer exveption when I start this activity, and I'm having some issues finding the culprit. This Activity is in my Manifest file. There are three classes that this Activity depends on. One of the activities extends the thread class. The classes aren't in my manifest.

Activity:

```
package com.example.soft;

import com.example.soft.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class PlayGame extends Activity {
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    private GraphicsMole im;
    private int currentMolePos = -1;
    private int scoreCurr = 0;
    private int lifeCurr = 9;
    private Handler step;
    private Handler Update;
    private MoleGame mg;
    private boolean isMole = true;
    private Mole mole = new Mole();
    private double prob=0.7;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(0);//Horizontal Screen Orientation      
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        final TextView scoreTview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);
        final TextView lifeTview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Life);
        final GridView gw = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        step = new ChangeImage();
        Update = new Handler();
        im = new GraphicsMole(this);
        gw.setAdapter(im);

        // ----------------------------

        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
                HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

        gw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                if (currentMolePos == position) {

                    Update.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if (isMole == true) {
                                scoreCurr = scoreCurr + 150;
                                scoreTview.setText("Score: " + scoreCurr);
                                scoreTview.refreshDrawableState();
                                if(scoreCurr==3000){
                                    setProbability(0.60);
                                    mg.setTimeToWait(700);

                                }
                                else if(scoreCurr==7500){
                                    setProbability(0.45);
                                    mg.setTimeToWait(500);
                                }
                            } 
                            else {
                                lifeCurr = lifeCurr - 1;
                                lifeTview.setText("Life: " + lifeCurr);
                                lifeTview.refreshDrawableState();
                                if (lifeCurr == 0) {
                                    mg.stopThread();

                                    Intent gameOverIntent = new Intent(
                                            PlayGame.this, GameMenu.class);
                                    gameOverIntent.putExtra("score", scoreCurr);
                                    startActivity(gameOverIntent);
                                    finish();

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        mg = new MoleGame(step);
        mg.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }

public Activity getActivity(){
        return this.getActivity();
    }
    private class ChangeImage extends Handler {
        Hole hole = new Hole();
        private int oldPosition = -1;

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

            currentMolePos = bundle.getInt("newPosition");
            if (Math.random() < prob) {
                im.setItem(currentMolePos, mole.getmole());
                isMole = true;
            } 
            else {
                im.setItem(currentMolePos, mole.getphone());
                isMole = false;
            }

            if (oldPosition != -1 && currentMolePos != oldPosition) {
                im.setItem(oldPosition, hole.getHole());
            }

            oldPosition = currentMolePos;
            im.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    public void setProbability(double prob){
        this.prob=prob;
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quitandbefree/com.example.quitandbefree.PlayGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1939)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:145)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1045)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4369)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:846)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at com.example.quitandbefree.PlayGame.onCreate(PlayGame.java:129)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
10-06 18:04:46.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     ... 11 more
```

EDIT! 
XML Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shadedbackground"
    tools:context=".PlayGame" >

    <!--
         The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc.
    -->

<!-- <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
    </ViewFlipper> 
    -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/Score" android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="50px" android:text="Score: "
        android:textColor="#FF0000" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="15px">

    </TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/Life" android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="50px" android:text="Life: "
        android:textColor="#FF0000" android:textSize="15px" android:textStyle="bold">

    </TextView>

    <GridView android:id="@+id/gridview" android:numColumns="4"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0px" android:horizontalSpacing="0px"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="600px">

    </GridView>

    <!--
         This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows.
    -->



</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Which line is `PlayGame.java:129`?

Comment: At 129 is: contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `fullscreen_content` view in your xml layout, so

```
findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
```

returns `null` and

```
contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

throws the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Here's the layout file, I do have Life within the xml.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see what happened now, this is my first time working with Full Screen Activities.

Comment: Great it helped :) Btw, if an answer was useful, consider upvoting/accepting so that other users can spot the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

as per ssantos answer you don't have fullscreen_content and fullscreen_content_controls too
so both of the following are being null;

```
final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
```

May be due to this

```
  setRequestedOrientation(0);//Horizontal Screen Orientation
```

User this

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```